# WiFi adapter not working Ubuntu 19.04 realtek 8822be in ASUS laptop

Tags: wireless, 19.04, realtek

it doesn't detect wifi, and if it does, it can't connect to them. LAN works fine, any idea?
I dual boot ubuntu 19.04 with W10